# apache - change directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ok here is the problem

I have access on the server only from directadmin and I want to change base directory

In public_html I have framework files and public directory and When I visit my site I want to run public folder

So the directory must be public_html/public not public_html/

P.s I don't want redirect

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to edit your virtualhost config and change the [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot) to `/absolute/path/to/public_html/public`